# Is the Euler prime of an odd perfect number a repunit, or otherwise?

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, prime-numbers, perfect-numbers

Let $N = {q^k}{n^2}$ be an odd perfect number given in Eulerian form (i.e., $q$ is prime with $\gcd(q,n)=1$ and $q \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$).  (That is, $2N=\sigma(N)$ where $\sigma$ is the classical sum-of-divisors function.)

Since $\gcd(q^k,\sigma(q^k))=1$, it follows that $q \mid \sigma(n^2)$.

My question is this:

> Is the Euler prime $q$ of an odd perfect number a [repunit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repunit), or otherwise?  Is there a research work out there that tackles this particular question?

Thanks!

Comment: Is there any reason to expect a result for this special form?

Comment: @Charles, well for one, repunit primes are *rare*, and we haven't found a single odd perfect number (OPN) *yet*.  So maybe (*just maybe*), the Euler prime of an OPN might be a repunit prime?  Your thoughts?

Comment: Posting a follow-up to this question now.

Comment: Here is the [second question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1188446), which I believe is more appropriate for this given problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*NO*, the Euler prime $q$ of an odd perfect number $N = {q^k}{n^2}$ is *not* a repunit, since repunit primes $p > 1$ satisfy $p \equiv 3 \pmod 4$, while it is known that the Euler prime $q$ satisfies $q \equiv 1 \pmod 4$.